# Size , Height, Width of range of excel cells lost after copying it to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Want to copy data from one sheet to another. However after copying data, it looses size of rows and columns.

```
 Sheets("Chart1").Range("A1:Q1000").Clear
 Sheets("UI Response").Range("A" & 1 & ":" & "B" & uiPerfTo).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Chart1").Range("A" & 1 & ":" & "B" & uiPerfTo)
```

Source Data - [image: Source Data Before Copy]

After Copy to another Sheet [image: After Copy, it looses size]

So size of rows and column is lost..How to maintain this using macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sheets("Chart1").Range("A1:Q1000").Clear

Sheets("UI Response").Range("A" & 1 & ":" & "B" & uiPerfTo).Copy
Sheets("Chart1").Range("A" & 1 & ":" & "B" & uiPerfTo).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
Sheets("Chart1").Range("A" & 1 & ":" & "B" & uiPerfTo).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: what did u mean by 'in word table goes out of margin of word'? contents in original sheet autofitted, were not they?